# ValueError(u"Invalid mode, expected 'c' or 'fortran', got f\x00o\x00r\x00t",)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-c-api

I am trying to import `sklearn.neighbors` in Python, and from there import `KNeighborsClassifier`. When I try to execute it in Python, I get a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError(u"Invalid mode, expected 'c' or 'fortran', got f\x00o\x00r\x00t",) in <module 'threading' from '/home/sjain55/anaconda/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored' .
```

A little gist of the code :

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)

selected_features = X[:, idx[0:num_fea]]

neigh.fit(selected_features[train], y[train]) //this is the line giving me the above error.
```

I've tried searching, but wasn't able to find why I am receiving such an error. Does anyone have any idea why I'm receiving this error?

Data printed on verbose

s1 : 18863

s : 11062

check2

I was called with 2464 arguments:

(1440, 1)

check

ck1

{'fisher_score': True, 'y': array([ 1,  1,  1, ..., 20, 20, 20], dtype=uint8), 'neighbor_mode': 'supervised'}

/home/sjain55/Desktop/FS_Package_DMML-master/FS_package/function/similarity_based/fisher_score.py:47: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  score = 1.0/lap_score - 1

Exception ValueError: ValueError(u"Invalid mode, expected 'c' or 'fortran', got f\x00o\x00r\x00t",) in  ignored

Comment: what is the form of your `selected_features[train]` and `y[train]`?

Comment: selected_features = X[:, idx[0:num_fea]] //here X is a 2D array

Comment: Do you have the last version of your packages ? I was running scikit learn v0.11 and had this problem. After updating scipy, and scikitlearn, it disapeared.

Comment: I am using latest versions of scipy(0.15.1) and sklearn(0.16.1) . Also when I am running the code through Python only, it executes. But when I embed Python in C++ it bombed out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out your problem, sklearn impose in some model that the data be in a specific order called `Fortran/C order` to fix that issues just add the `order='F'` or `order='C'` to your `trainX` and `trainY` data this way:

```py
selected_features[train] = numpy.array(selected_features[train],order='F')
y[train] = numpy.array(y[train],order='F')
```

Note:

> Order argument Specify the order of the array. If order is ‘C’, then the array will be in C-contiguous order (last-index varies the fastest). If order is ‘F’, then the returned array will be in Fortran-contiguous order (first-index varies the fastest). If order is ‘A’, then the returned array may be in any order (either C-, Fortran-contiguous, or even discontiguous).

Comment: First i just simply inserted your suggestion in my code and i got the below error  'Exception NameError: "global name 'array' is not defined"

Comment: Now, i changed your to selected_features[train] = np.asarray(selected_features[train],order='F')  and got back the earlier error :(

Comment: it's weird... can you print some of your data?

Comment: Just posted. Also I am embedding python in C++, so this python module is called from C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your strings are encoded by default with utf8 and you are calling something expecting ASCII strings. The string `f\x00o\x00r\x00t` are the first 7 bytes of the string literal `u"fortran"` which is the default string encoding in python 3 or in 2 if file encoding is set to utf8.

Change `"fortran"` to `r"fortran"` to pass a raw ASCII string instead of a utf one. If `r"fortran"` still gives you wide characters you can force an old (ASCII) string by using `str("fortran")`.

Comment: Where do I need to change?